# Skipping a Splash Screen

Tags: java, android, android-activity, splash-screen, dynamic-splash-screen

I have designed a splash screen with a button. The Java code is as below. The layout of the splash contains some texts with animation and button named skipped splash screen. When the user presses the button, the splash screen has to stop immediately and open the next activity. But when I open the splash screen and press skip button, the next activity opens but after the duration for which splash screen has to run gets over, again the activity opens. How to stop the splash screen when a user presses the skip button?

```
  public class Qz1 extends Activity {

        TextView a;
        TextView b;
        TextView c;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_qz1);
            a =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.roundOnea22);
            a.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Qz1.this, R.anim.anim_slide_in_left));
            b =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.roundOneb);
            b.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Qz1.this, R.anim.anim_slide_in_right));
            c =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.roundme);
            c.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Qz1.this, R.anim.anim_slide_in_left));




            Thread thread = new Thread(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try{
                    sleep(3200);

                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Qone.class));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        };
        thread.start();

    }

    public void round1(View v){
       Intent i = new Intent(Qz1.this, Qone.class);
       startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your button initialization and onclick event listener?

Comment: Add your remaining code

Comment: I haven't initialized the button. I have used the onClick method. Do I have to use onclick event listener?

Comment: use finish() where it should be closed

Comment: then how your activity will find that your onClick method is to call on button present on Splash Activity

Comment: Mohit if I use onClick event listener, what is the piece of code I must insert to stop the splash screen?

Comment: I think the onClickListener is set in the xml

Comment: please check the chat, I need some more infos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose you want to keep your first activity in the background, but you do not want the thread to re-open the second activity as soon as it has finished sleeping.

In order to achieve that, you can make your "thread" a global variable of a custom `Thread` class. You can define this as an inner class of your activity:

```
MyThread thread;
```

and the class definition:

```
private class MyThread extends Thread
{
    public boolean bRun = true;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            sleep(3200);
            if (bRun)
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class));
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

In `onCreate()`, you write

```
thread = new MyThread();
thread.start();
```

Then you can change your "onClick" method like this:

```
public void round1(View v){
   if (thread != null && thread.isAlive())
   {
       thread.bRun = false;
   }
   Intent i = new Intent(Qz1.this, Qone.class);
   startActivity(i);
}
```

This will keep the thread from starting the second activity, if it has been started by clicking the button.

Comment: thread.bRun = false;

This is line is shown as error. The correction suggested is to rename the file. What to do?

Comment: @Suresh Anand - "File"? that's strange. OK, then make your IDE happy and name the variable something else, not "thread"

Comment: Yeah did that. Now the error is bRun cannot be resolved into a field or is not a field.

Comment: but you did copy my version of your thread with the public boolean variable named "bRun"?

Comment: @Suresh Anand - ok, I'm working around that - please wait a minute. I think one should use an inner class for the thread. Sorry I did not take the time to test this first :(

Comment: @SureshAnand - I introduced an inner class extending Thread. This way, the boolean is "visible" in the onClickListener. The code in "onCreate()" is reduced to two lines, the rest stays like before.

Comment: Still the same error persists. Cannot be resolved into field.

Comment: @Suresh Anand - ok, but meanwhile I have your sample running ( and working, finally ;) ) in my emulator.

Comment: @Suresh Anand - so let's check this together. 1) You need a global variable of class "MyThread". 2) you need the inner class called MyThread which extends Thread. OK so far?

Comment: What can be the possible solution?

Comment: @Suresh Anand - it's working for my emulator, we'll get it to work for yours :)  - where did you copy the code for the MyThread class? Can the IDE find it?

Comment: I am trying to put the code here but the site says the message is too long. Can you start a chat with me?

Comment: @Suresh Anand - maybe we'll get the chat started automatically if we write lots of comments

Comment: I will put my code in 2 or 3  comments

public class Qz1 extends Activity {
 Thread thread;
 TextView a;
 Button p;
 TextView b;
 TextView c;
 
 
 
 private class MyThread extends Thread
 {
     public boolean bRun = true;

     @Override
     public void run()
     {
         try
         {
             sleep(3200);
             if (bRun)
             {
                 startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Qone.class));
             }
         }
         catch (InterruptedException e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }

 }

Comment: @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_qz1);
  
  
 
  
 
  
  
  thread = new MyThread();
  thread.start();
}
 
 public void round1(View v){
     if (thread != null && thread.isAlive())
     {
      thread.bRun = false;
     }
     Intent i = new Intent(Qz1.this, Qone.class);
     startActivity(i);
  }
}

Comment: @Suresh Anand - OK, I see where the problem is: you still write "Thread thread:". But it has to be "MyThread thread;" now

Comment: I have added animation for activity transition. When I start the activity by clicking the button, I am getting the animation. But when the activity starts itself after the splash screen is over, the animation is not coming. How to solve that?

Comment: @Suresh Anand - we finälly have a chat :) please post your code there. I'm a little busy now, but I'll look into it in the next 24 hours. Alternatively maybe you could ask a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95453/discussion-between-0x0nosugar-and-suresh-anand).

Comment: yes this is good approach only that you can have `boolean` as global variable and buddy at least accept the answer if your problem is solved so this will help other too with same problem..

Answer (score 1):

It's best practice to use Async Tasks for wait/sleep scenarios, such as for splash screens, but requirements can differ.

Anyway this is my way to call a splash screen:

Create the `AsyncTask` first.

```
private class SplashTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        finish();

            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
}
```

Then call this where ever you want: on button click, on start, or on create:

```
new SplashTask().execute();
```

Comment: this will not stop splash screen thread when button is clicked

Comment: this will not work it will take 2 sec after clicking button

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be using sleep(2000)

use an animationlistener (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html)

when onAnimationEnd is triggered call startActivity.

Answer (score 1):

I think best practice here would be to use a Handler.

You can do it like this:

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity{

private Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Settign the splashscreen with the button i suppose
    setContentView(R.id.splashcreen);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startNextActivity();
        }
    }, 2000);
}

public void startNextActivity(){
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Qone.class));
}

public void skipSplashScreen(){
    if (handler != null)
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

    startNextActivity();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // clear handler on stop
    if (handler != null)
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}
}
```

CAll skipSplashScreen() when user press the button and the handler will stop so the timer stops and you go to next activity manually by calling method startNextActivity().

Answer (score 0):

try this in the splash activity

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLayout);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this,TargetActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: won't work because the thread will still be running, and cause the activity to restart